# Automatic Lock Screen prevention if the line is engaged

Tags: lock-screens, calls, motorola-atrix-4g

I am an Atrix owner. One thing makes me annoyed. I try to place a call and if the line is somehow engaged, the phone automatically locks the screen. Is there any way that I bypass this automatic feature and use the gadget without hassle?
Thanks in advance for the repsonse.

Comment: What do you mean by engaged? That the line/number you are calling is busy?

Comment: yeap, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are rooted, disable your *Proximity Sensor* in a call. To do so, add following line to `/system/build.prop` file: `gsm.proximity.enable=false`.

If you don't use *Proximity Sensor* other than in call, you can disable it fully. To do so, use [Hardware Disabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hatcyl.android.Hardware_Disabler) app. But, make sure you have selected correct driver of proximity sensor, otherwise you will brick your device. To find correct driver of proximity sensor, you can either Google or find it using [Android Sensor Box](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.androidsensorbox) app.

Plus, make sure to make screen timeout period long. You can use Widgetsoid app (or, other toggle apps) to make it infinite.

Comment: great and many thanks, I will give it a go... however, I am compelled to ask; will this brick be the soft or hard?

Comment: That depends on what you have disabled. Re-flashing generally solves the problem, but there're chances of permanent hardware damage...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way. The phone is like an app, it will run until it times out and brings you to the lock screen. It happens a lot in games and stuff when you are not active and the phone thinks you are away so it turns the screen off to save battery. It happens to me when I talk on the phone for a long period of time. You can either completely disable the lock screen, or keep it on. I don't believe that there is alternative. The lock screen does this for your own "safety" and there are no exceptions. You can, however, extend the time limit you have until your phone locks itself.

Comment: on the other hand, I can't help thinking the same; the phone does what it has to do :)